# syncdb is not creating tables again?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am stuck with this issue: I had some migration problems and I tried many times and on the way, I deleted migrations and tried again and even deleted one table in db. there is no data in db, so I don't have to fear. But now if I try `syncdb` it is not creating the table I deleted manually.

Honestly, I get really stuck every time with this such kind of migration issues.

What should I do to create the tables again?

Comment: Can you add you settings.py file and may be one of your models file and the project structure from root to one models.py file

Comment: If you are not worried aobut data, create a new database and start afresh

Comment: @karthikr, creating new db is a rude solution, is there really no solution here?

Comment: why is it rude? You dont care about the data, and when you do syncdb, you start afresh anyways.

Comment: @karthikr, you are right. but now i did syncdb --all. it worked now. but i dont know why it did :)

Comment: @doniyor Wow, your `syncdb --all` really works!! Thank you so much.Suprisingly found the solution in a comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure you are deleting south history and to use syncdb as if no south exists, you have to delete migrations in two places:

1. In the database: remove tables created by south
2. Migration files: remove folders used by south. They are like "app_name/migrations"

If you don't need any data in your database (because it is testing for example), instead of remove only south tables, y recommend to do a complete reset. The commando to do that is

```
python manage.py reset_db --router=default
```

Hope it helps!

**Some extra help**

Generally, when you use syncdb and south is in your INSTALLED_APPS you get a message saying that some apps won't be synced and that you have to use migrations. Try to do a syncdb and look at the apps that can't be synced. If there are some of them, remove the "migrations" folder inside that apps and make a syncdb again. The app should't appear again in the list that can't be synced.

Answer (score 0):

are you using `south`?

If you are, there is a migration history database that exists.
Make sure to delete the row mentionnaing the migration you want to run again.

Comment: i deleted all migrations

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the comand reset in the app, something like that:

```
python manage.py reset my_app
```

Comment: i did, it deletes only data and doesnot create tables

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the migration file and running `python manage.py syncdb`.